# typeahead.js not getting data from remote data source in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, typeahead.js, typeahead

I'm trying to implement typeahead.js in asp.net web forms app.

I have a generic handler which returns list of strings, in my case, name of schools.

This is the code for the handler:

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            List<string> strSchools = new List<string>();
            string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
            var schools =
               DataLayer.GetSchools()
                   .Select(s => s).OrderBy(s => s.Name);

            foreach (SchoolItem school in schools)
            {
                if (prefixText != string.Empty)
                {
                    prefixText = prefixText.ToLower();
                    if (school.Name.ToLower().Contains(prefixText))
                    {
                        strSchools.Add(school.Name);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                   strSchools.Add(school.Name);
                }
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            context.Response.Write(jsSerializer.Serialize(strSchools));
        }
```

In the js code I have this:

```
  function pageLoad(sender, args) {

            var schoolList = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('names'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                limit: 10,
                remote: 'SchoolListHandler.ashx'
            });

            // kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
            schoolList.initialize();
            // debugger;

            // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
            // options being used
            $('#txtSchool').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'name',
                displayKey: 'Name',
                // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
                // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
                source: schoolList.ttAdapter()
            });
  }
```

For some reason as I said I'm not able to get to the handler and get the results back.

Do you guys see anything wrong?

Comment: Can you mention the error you got ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things jump out
First, check your remote call from JS,

```
remote: {
        url: '/SchoolListHandler.ashx?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
```

Next, check that you're searching on the input parameter named "query"

```
string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["query"]; // not q
```

Finally, make sure you're setting the content type of your return.  Add this to the end of your .ashx

```
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
```